# How to pause animation smoothly?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, cabasicanimation

I created a wheel of fortune and I'm having trouble to stop it.
how do I smoothly stop a user initiated, gesture controlled, circular object in motion.  I am able to stop the object abruptly, but would like to have a gradual and smooth stop.

```
   let spinAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
   spinAnimation.fromValue = 0
    // goes to 360 ( 2 * π )
    spinAnimation.toValue = M_PI*2
    // define how long it will take to complete a 360
    spinAnimation.duration = 10
    // make it spin infinitely
    spinAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    // do not remove when completed
    spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
    // specify the fill mode
    spinAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    // and the animation acceleration
    spinAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:    kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

    counterView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    // add the animation to the button layer
    counterView.layer.addAnimation(spinAnimation, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
```

Answer (score 1):

change
`spinAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:   kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)`

to
`spinAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)`
the ease out should slow the animation as time progresses.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Predefined_Timing_Functions for details on timing

Comment: Any example of it? I'm trying to make the wheel to stop but not  back to the start point.

Comment: Then do not do value of `M_PI * 2`, instead do `M_PI * some number based on random or force`  Make sure the random number is a decimal, otherwise you will only be doing intervals of 180